# Return HTTP json response

Tags: python, sanic

I'm quite new in developing REST API using python.
I want to return this list as json in response. I use response from sanic.

```
response_data = [{'error': False, 'errormsg': '', 'status': '200'}, {'data': {1: {'name': 'sosialisasi', 'm_value': 77, 'c_value': 876, 'cu_value': 568, 'cl_value': 468, 'independent_vars': {'jumlah hari': {None: {'val_name': None, 'value': None}}, 'tingkatan sosialisasi': {2: {'val_name': 'kecamatan', 'value': '0.5'}, 1: {'val_name': 'kabupaten', 'value': '0.75'}}}}}}]

response.json(response_data, 200)
```

But I get error `TypeError: expected bytes, str found`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/dewi/saniccrudenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 939, in handle_request
    response = await response
  File "/home/dewi/anomali/operations.py", line 183, in getAsb
    return response.json(response_data, 200)
  File "/home/dewi/saniccrudenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/response.py", line 210, in json
    dumps(body, **kwargs),
TypeError: expected bytes, str found
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
When I use json.dumps on response_data, it isn't error.
But it return json string like this

```
"[{\"error\": false, \"errormsg\": \"\", \"status\": \"200\"}, {\"data\": {\"1\": {\"name\": \"sosialisasi\", \"m_value\": 77, \"c_value\": 876, \"cu_value\": 568, \"cl_value\": 468, \"independent_vars\": {\"jumlah hari\": {\"null\": {\"val_name\": null, \"value\": null}}, \"tingkatan sosialisasi\": {\"2\": {\"val_name\": \"kecamatan\", \"value\": \"0.5\"}, \"1\": {\"val_name\": \"kabupaten\", \"value\": \"0.75\"}}}}}}]"
```

What I want is json object, something like this

```
[
{
    "error": false,
    "errormsg": "",
    "status": "200"
},
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nama": "test1",
            "kode": "101"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nama": "test2",
            "kode": "202"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: Could you please post full traceback?

Comment: I've edited the question with traceback

Comment: Do you have ujson installed? The issue could be there, as sanic tries to import ujson first and uses that to dump json.

Comment: No, I installed sanic without ujson

Comment: ujson could've been installed on separate occasion. Could you please confirm that you are unable to `import ujson` in your app? Otherwise, this error doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I add `import ujson` and it's working now.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Now its not working again, it has the same error as before. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `None` as a keyword:

```
response_data = [
        {"error": False, "errormsg": "", "status": "200"},
        {
            "data": {
                1: {
                    "name": "sosialisasi",
                    "m_value": 77,
                    "c_value": 876,
                    "cu_value": 568,
                    "cl_value": 468,
                    "independent_vars": {
                        "jumlah hari": {
                            None: {"val_name": None, "value": None}
                        },
                        "tingkatan sosialisasi": {
                            2: {"val_name": "kecamatan", "value": "0.5"},
                            1: {"val_name": "kabupaten", "value": "0.75"},
                        },
                    },
                }
            }
        },
    ]
```

If you change:

```
"jumlah hari": {
    None: {"val_name": None, "value": None}
},
```

to

```
"jumlah hari": {
    "None": {"val_name": None, "value": None}
},
```

It will work as expected.

```
$ curl localhost:9999/                                                                                                                                          (env: sanic) 
[{"error":false,"errormsg":"","status":"200"},{"data":{"1":{"name":"sosialisasi","m_value":77,"c_value":876,"cu_value":568,"cl_value":468,"independent_vars":{"jumlah hari":{"None":{"val_name":null,"value":null}},"tingkatan sosialisasi":{"2":{"val_name":"kecamatan","value":"0.5"},"1":{"val_name":"kabupaten","value":"0.75"}}}}}}]
```

### JSON Spec:

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens surrounding zero or more name/value pairs. A  name  is  a string.

[Source](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)